# Wordress and packery.js integration issues but works on non wordpress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, packery

I am trying to use packery.js on my wordpress theme, but it doesn't work.

It works when i use the exact same code on a test html site. It also works in wordpress when i initiate it with the html method, but as i also needs to use "imageloaded" i have to make it work with java script.

My guess is that something in wordpress is disrupting my jQuery or something, but i don't know what i could be?

I have tried using different versions of jquery but it dosent work.

My script:

```
var container = document.querySelector('#content');
var $pckry;
var $pckry = new Packery( container, {
// options
itemSelector: '.item',
gutter: 0,
});
// initialize Packery after all images have loaded
imagesLoaded( container, function() {
$pckry = new Packery( container );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i figured it out. first, it doesn't need jquery to work. The issue was that i had places the script in the header, and for some reason i can't explain it has to be placed in the footer, just above the closing body tag.

Like this:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<script>
var container = document.querySelector('#blog-list-center');
var $pckry;
var $pckry = new Packery( container, {
// options
itemSelector: '.item',
gutter: 0,
});
// initialize Packery after all images have loaded
imagesLoaded( container, function() {
$pckry = new Packery( container );
});
</script>
</body>
```